# How can I git push local commit after pull new commits

Tags: git

It happened by my carelessness.

1. I modified scripts on the live server and commit (B) it, but not push it. It has been serving.

   - Live server: A -> B
   - remote Git: A
2. My coworker modified on his machine and commit, push, and pull on the live server.

   - Live server: A -> B -> C
   - remote Git: A -> C

I tried to push my commit B and I met this error message.

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
```

How can I push my commit safely?

- Live server: A -> B -> C
- remote Git: A -> B -> C (or A -> C -> B_new ?)

There are no duplications between commit B and C.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Have you tried pulling before pushing?

Comment: I think most of your problems here is that you're asking how to do a broken workflow safely. The tooling isn't built to handle broken workflows, it assumes you're trying your best to do it right to begin with. You should effectively do the same as your coworker, work against the remote and only pull on the live server to update it. If you still need to commit on the live server, you should push from there as well to make the remote up-to-date.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think your live server history is like you showed because if your coworker pulled his C into the live server there should now be a merge commit after B and C, merging them together. If your coworker pulled with rebase (or something similar), then he has effectively rewritten history and he should clean up after him. Basically, the C on the remote server (in A->C) cannot be the same as on the live server (A->B->C) as the hash would be different.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, I broke the workflow. I should do hot fix and forgot to push it. As you mention @Lasse V Karlsen, my commit has been merged on live server but I cannot push to remote even it dosenot make a conflict. I need a super safe method to recover this mistake.